# Under what circumstances would a table get converted to a dictionary?

Tags: kdb

I'm doing a relatively boring query:

```
returns: select s: avg (target1 * signum p), l: avg(lR) by date from z
```

Which produces something that looks like:

```
date      | s             l            
----------| ---------------------------
2001.01.02| 0.02929124    -0.02979896  
2001.01.03| -0.01870611   0.04020953   
2001.01.04| -0.006486651  -0.015966    
2001.01.05| 0.002188851   -0.02215498  
2001.01.08| 0.0001548752  0.001631526
```

The problem is, though `z` in my query is a table 98h, the query result is a dictionary 99h, which is causing my problems further down in my code.

What could possibly be causing the type cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental of this is that adding a key using your "by date" filter creates a keyed table. Keyed tables are simply dictionaries mapping a table of keys to a table of values. More on this can be seen here:
https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#841-keyed-table

Because your avg(lR) relies on the "by date" filter the only way around this is to manually unkey your returns dictionary using:

```
returns: 0!select s: avg (target1 * signum p), l: avg(lR) by date from z
```

This should unkey your table and give you a type of 98h, hopefully avoiding any errors further down the line.

Comment: Thank you @nhughes!